# how to change wallpaper from inside a service class?

Tags: android, service

i want to change the wallpaper of my phone in an activity every few minutes...

i was using this in my main activity which was working fine there>

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;

    Bitmap bmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.superman);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmap2, width, height, true);

            WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

but now on my service i can't use this code... since it doesn't work.. 
(can't use the getWindowManager method)
how do i do the same from inside a service class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but now on my service i can't use this code... since it doesn't work.. (can't use the getWindowManager method)

`getWindowManager()` is a method on Activity, and when you extends `Service` you are not on an `Activity`

> how do i do the same from inside a service class ?

You can call the method with other way doing this :

```
WindowManager wm= (WindowManager) getSystemService(YOURCONTEXT.WINDOW_SERVICE); 
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Also you can do it with `DisplayMetrics` as you did out of `Service`

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
```

Don't forget to add this on your `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
```

Comment: i could do it but later on it gets stuck on >    Bitmap bmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.superman);,

Comment: @user2560571 What do you mean?

Comment: if i change it then it doesn't do errors but then when i run it in the simulator the app crashes...

Comment: 09-01 18:55:54.699    8074-8089/? E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 74649612 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM"
09-01 18:55:54.699    8074-8089/? D/skia﹕ --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap

Comment: Try to use a image with low dimension

Comment: it's the exact dimention as my phone is.... and if i do it in the main activity it works fine...maybe it's becouse it's simulator ?

Comment: I just tested it... and it works for me (I'm working on a real device)

Comment: @user2560571 I'm glad :P feel free to upvote and mark it as a correct if my support helped you! ^^ Happy coding